# CSS Transform Rotate 3D - Hover on each corner of a card

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-transforms

I am trying to use css 3d rotation to simulate pushing down on a card when the mouse hovers over it divided into 4 quadrants. Top Left, Top Right, Bottom Left, Bottom Right. I got the top left/right to work but no matter what combination I try I can't get the bottom effects to work the same as the top. Any idea of how to get the bottom left/right to look correct like they are being pushed down the same way the top corners seem to look correct? Also, if there is a better way to do this altogether in css/js let me know I am just messing around with these css transformations for the first time.

I added shadows to try and help "sell" the effect of the bottom being pushed in while top pops out but it still looks wrong. Might just be me, trick of the eye of something.

```js
function ThzhotspotPosition(evt, el, percent) {
  var left = el.offset().left;
  var top = el.offset().top;
  if (percent) {
    x = (evt.pageX - left) / el.outerWidth() * 100;
    y = (evt.pageY - top) / el.outerHeight() * 100;
  } else {
    x = (evt.pageX - left);
    y = (evt.pageY - top);
  }

  return {
    x: Math.round(x),
    y: Math.round(y)
  };
}

$(".card").mousemove(function(e) {
  var hp = ThzhotspotPosition(e, $(this), true); // true = percent | false or no attr = px

  if (hp.x >= 50 && hp.y >= 50) {
    $(this).removeClass(function(index, className) {
      return (className.match(/(^|\s)roll-\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
    }).addClass("roll-BR");
  } else if (hp.x >= 50 && hp.y < 50) {
    $(this).removeClass(function(index, className) {
      return (className.match(/(^|\s)roll-\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
    }).addClass("roll-TR");
  } else if (hp.x < 50 && hp.y >= 50) {
    $(this).removeClass(function(index, className) {
      return (className.match(/(^|\s)roll-\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
    }).addClass("roll-BL");
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass(function(index, className) {
      return (className.match(/(^|\s)roll-\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
    }).addClass("roll-TL");
  }

  $('#debug').text(hp.x + '%x' + ' ' + hp.y + '%y');
});


$(".card").hover(
  function(e) {
    //$( this ).addClass( "roll-left" );

  },
  function() {
    $(this).removeClass(function(index, className) {
      return (className.match(/(^|\s)roll-\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
    });
  }
);
```

```css
.card {
    width: 100px;
    height: 150px;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
    transition: transform 1s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.card.roll-TL {
    transform: rotate3d(1, -1, 0, 20deg);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 13px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.41); 
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 13px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.41);
    
}
.card.roll-TR {
    transform: rotate3d(-1, -1, 0, -20deg);
    -webkit-box-shadow: -5px 5px 13px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.41); 
    box-shadow: -5px 5px 13px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.41);
}

.card.roll-BL {
    transform: rotate3d(-1, -1, 0, 20deg);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px -5px 13px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.41); 
    box-shadow: 5px -5px 13px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.41);
}

.card.roll-BR {
    transform: rotate3d(1, -1, 0, -20deg);
    -webkit-box-shadow: -5px -5px 13px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.41); 
    box-shadow: -5px -5px 13px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.41);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">Testing</div>
<div id="debug"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your js code correct (as I don't see problem when I run it) and just adjust some css.

```js
function ThzhotspotPosition(evt, el, percent) {
  var left = el.offset().left;
  var top = el.offset().top;
  if (percent) {
    x = (evt.pageX - left) / el.outerWidth() * 100;
    y = (evt.pageY - top) / el.outerHeight() * 100;
  } else {
    x = (evt.pageX - left);
    y = (evt.pageY - top);
  }

  return {
    x: Math.round(x),
    y: Math.round(y)
  };
}

$(".card").mousemove(function(e) {
  var hp = ThzhotspotPosition(e, $(this), true); // true = percent | false or no attr = px

  if (hp.x >= 50 && hp.y >= 50) {
    $(this).removeClass(function(index, className) {
      return (className.match(/(^|\s)roll-\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
    }).addClass("roll-BR");
  } else if (hp.x >= 50 && hp.y < 50) {
    $(this).removeClass(function(index, className) {
      return (className.match(/(^|\s)roll-\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
    }).addClass("roll-TR");
  } else if (hp.x < 50 && hp.y >= 50) {
    $(this).removeClass(function(index, className) {
      return (className.match(/(^|\s)roll-\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
    }).addClass("roll-BL");
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass(function(index, className) {
      return (className.match(/(^|\s)roll-\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
    }).addClass("roll-TL");
  }

  $('#debug').text(hp.x + '%x' + ' ' + hp.y + '%y');
});


$(".card").hover(
  function(e) {
    //$( this ).addClass( "roll-left" );

  },
  function() {
    $(this).removeClass(function(index, className) {
      return (className.match(/(^|\s)roll-\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
    });
  }
);
```

```css
.card {
  width: 200px;
  height: 280px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  transition: transform 1s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

/*the backside*/
.card:after{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  left:0;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;
  background: gray;
  transform: translateZ(-10px);
}

.card.roll-TL {
  transform: rotate3d(1, -1, 0, 20deg);
}

.card.roll-TR {
  transform: rotate3d(-1, -1, 0, -20deg);
}

.card.roll-BL {
  transform: rotate3d(-1, -1, 0, 20deg);
}

.card.roll-BR {
  transform: rotate3d(1, -1, 0, -20deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">Testing</div>
<div id="debug"></div>
```

Comment: When I run yours it still looks like the the bottom is lifted up and top is pushed down instead of the reverse.

Comment: @Danny it should be correct. just because there is no shadow, you cannot tell the difference.

Comment: I was wondering if it was just a visual perspective thing or not. Its more noticeable when you replace the solid color block with like a playing card it just "looks" right on the top and wrong on the bottom. Do you know if it's possible to cast a shadow or do anything that would help make it visually look correct on the bottom ones?

Comment: I edited the OP and added a shadow that changes depending on the location to see if that helps but it still visually looks off. It's probably just me it's protect technically correct and just eye tricks going on.

Comment: @Danny I tried add a backside (using pseudo element, but you can use real element as well, and you can add all 6-side if you want), I think it look better now.

Comment: That did seem to help some I added a shadow to that as well box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75); inside your new element and it helped even more. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Oh your code snippet part broke so it can't be run on your post btw.